# How does application use hwui.so in Android?

Tags: android, graphics

Recently, I was studying the source code under libs/hwui.
I study from the drag operation of launcher app.
I want to know how app use hardware acceleration with hwui.so.
Is there any material of hwui?

Thanks.
James.